# Extra Domain (TLD) in Google Breadcrumb

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool, breadcrumbs

We are using structured data breadcrumbs, and everything looks good on desktop, but on mobile it shows extra `.io` after the root. I'm not really sure what might be causing this / whether it's from something in the markup, or that can be configured from Google Search Console.

Example URL: `https://radar.io/blog/radar-shopping-retail-playbook`

[image]

Comment: Well now looks fine to me.[![see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4dXJ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4dXJ.jpg)
This could have been a crawling issue

Comment: It appears this is dependent on user location Whereas, @cedverd doesn't show the extra TLD (he's in India per his profile), I do see it (located in USA). However, if I change my Google settings to India (instead of current location), the extra TLD disappears. Not sure why it only happens on mobile and not desktop. Below are images for India and USA. Screenshot with setting set to India: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcAuc.jpg Screenshot with setting set to USA:https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6AsH.jpg